# jQuery: adding exceptions to focus out event

Tags: jquery, exception, focus, textarea

I am currently using the following code to change data entered in a textarea to html entered into a paragraph element on my website.

Changes are made when the user loses focus on the textarea element, however I would like to add exceptions. At the moment I have code that will wrap selected text in the textarea in [b] [/b] (bb code tags). However when you click on the link that calls this function the textarea loses focus and changes to a paragraph.

How can I add exceptions to focusout? so that when any element with the class textEdit is clicked that is considered the exception and the code to replace the textarea is not run?

```
$("textarea").live('focusout', function (e) {

var $target = $(event.target);

if ( $target.is(".textEdit") ) {

  } else {
var itemContent = $(this).val();

itemContent = htmlStrip(itemContent);

    itemContent = itemContent.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>"); // New lines
        //itemContent = itemContent.replace(/\s/g, " &nbsp;"); // Spaces

    // Formatting replacements
    itemContent = itemContent
        .replace(/\[b\]/gi, "<b>")
        .replace(/\[\/b\]/gi, "</b>")
        .replace(/\[i\]/gi, "<i>")
        .replace(/\[\/i\]/gi, "</i>")
        .replace(/\[s\]/gi, "<s>")
        .replace(/\[\/s\]/gi, "</s>")

        $(this).replaceWith("<p class='notes'>"+ itemContent +"</p>");

}

});
```

Thanks, as always for any advice!

**Edit: Sat 31 March 10:30am BST**

I have also tried:

```
if ($("#bold").is(":focus"))
```

and getting the active element $(document.activeElement) which only returns BODY when you click on anything. Really really stuck with this one would love any assistance or advice on how to proceed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it with timeouts...

```
var renderHandler;

$("textarea").live('focusout', function (e) {
   var currentNote = this;
   renderHandler = setTimeout( function(){ renderNote(currentNote); }, 50);
});

// handle exceptions
$('#bold, #other_exception_element, .and_yet_another_exception').live('focusin', function (e) {
   clearTimeout(renderHandler);
});


function renderNote( note ){

    var itemContent = $(note).val();

    itemContent = htmlStrip(itemContent);

    itemContent = itemContent.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>"); // New lines
        //itemContent = itemContent.replace(/\s/g, " &nbsp;"); // Spaces

    // Formatting replacements
    itemContent = itemContent
        .replace(/\[b\]/gi, "<b>")
        .replace(/\[\/b\]/gi, "</b>")
        .replace(/\[i\]/gi, "<i>")
        .replace(/\[\/i\]/gi, "</i>")
        .replace(/\[s\]/gi, "<s>")
        .replace(/\[\/s\]/gi, "</s>");

    $(note).replaceWith("<p class='notes'>"+ itemContent +"</p>");
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a whirl, I did think about timeouts but it seems like there should be a way to capture the click event of an element and use that as the exception. After 3 days banging my head against this though I'm desperate! :)

Comment: You can't really, because the focusout happens before any event that happens on another element.. It makes sense if you think the logic of the order in which things have to happen.. You can't logically click on something while something else still retains focus...

Comment: Yeah that does make sense, I think I've been coming at it completely the wrong way and looking at it so much that I can't see the wood for the trees! just tested your solution and it works perfectly! thank you SO much!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in safari or chrome, in chrome it applies the style then focuses out and in safari it doesn't apply the style. Any ideas? Webkit seems to continue with the renderNote function regardless.

Comment: @KryptoniteDove, try increasing the timeout delay ... (*the 50*)